# file descriptor redirection in docker

Tags: bash, docker, io-redirection

I want to be able to pipe some content into a docker process without clobbering it's stdin.

I thought I could do this by opening a new file descriptor in bash before spawning the docker process, then consuming this descriptor within the docker process. However it doesn't work

outside docker:

```
exec 4<>somefile.txt
docker run --rm -i image cmd args > output.txt
```

inside docker:

```
exec 4>file.txt # also tried without the exec
do something with file.txt
```

The docker container stops when it reaches the `4>file.txt` line.

It must be an atomic action, so I can't use `docker cp` or anything like that.
Also, the docker image does not expose any network ports, so netcat cannot be used.
I would prefer to not use any complex docker mounts.

STDIN is required for other purposes, so I can't clobber that

Are there any other options for getting the file content into a transient container for the use of a single command?

Comment: `docker run -v file.txt` ?

Comment: ok, the mount syntax is not nearly as complex as I thought!

Comment: This doesn't work. -v always creates a directory in the container, not a file

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach here is to mount the current directory into the container.  You can choose any directory name inside the container, and should try to avoid hiding the script itself with the mount.

```
docker run --rm -i -v $PWD:/data image \
  cmd -i /data/file.txt -o /data/output.txt --other-args
```

Filesystem permissions can be tricky, on both sides of this: you can name *any* directory in the first half of the `-v` option, even system directories like `/etc`; and if the process inside the container runs as a non-root user it might have trouble reading the files in the directory you mount in.

You can [bind-mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) either files or directories, but with the one caveat that they must exist on the host first, or else Docker will create a directory for you (even if you wanted a file; and likely owned by root and not your local user).

Comment: mounting the current directory is not going to work in my case for security reasons, but I think creating a temp directory and mounting that will be the way to go